# Swift: Regular expression to detect non alpha numeric characters

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to build an regular expression to detect string containing alphanumeric characters and special characters but so for I haven't found the right what to do it. Here is my code:

```
var str = "asda~dd.ASD98ASD09ASD098ASD098ADS908"
let myRegEx = "^[a-z]{7}\\.[A-Z0-9]{28}$"
if (str.rangeOfString(myRegEx,options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil) {

         str = "itwork.yes"   
}
```

Any of you knows how can I build my regular expression to detect non alphanumeric characters ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `rangeOfCharacter`?

```
// Choose character set and add all characters that you want to check for besides the alphanumeric characters
let set = CharacterSet.alphanumerics.union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".\\"))

// Check for the range of the characters in the string
let range = str.rangeOfCharacter(from: set, options: .regularExpression)
```

That's probably one of the cleanest ways doing this.

EDIT:

If you want to detect only *non-alphanumeric* characters, use `set.inverse` instead of simply `set` when calling the range function.

Comment: How do you detect the length of the substring?

Comment: @user2924482 when you only want to know, _if_ the string contains any of these characters, checking for != nil is sufficient, otherwise you can't use this method, as the length is always one! It only searches for a single character, which the set you specified contains